# Select results by multiple speciality and locations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am new to MVC & EF. I am developing a site for search doctors by speciality and location.
 doctors are multiple locations(Practice) and multiple Specialty's.  Here is my model:

```
public class Doctors
{
    public int DoctorsID { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
    public int Fee { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Practice> Practice { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DoctorSpecialtys> DoctorSpecialtys { get; set; }
}

public class Practice
{
    public int PracticeID { get; set; }
    public string clinicname { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public int DoctorsID { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctors Doctors { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorSpecialtys
{
    public int DoctorSpecialtysID { get; set; }
    public string specialty { get; set; }
    public int DoctorsID { get; set; }
    public virtual Doctors Doctors { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get the result based on specialty and location. Here is my control Action Result:

```
public ActionResult Index(string specialty, string location,string currentFilter,int? page)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = specialty;
    ViewBag.loca = location;

    DoctorsContext db = new DoctorsContext();
    var docs = from cust in db.doctorsinfo.Where(c => c.DoctorspecialityName.Contains(specialty)).OrderBy(s=>s.Fee)
               select cust;

    //docs = docs.Distinct();
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View(docs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    //return View(docs);

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to fetch doctors results based on my specialty and location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var docs = from cust in db.doctorsinfo.
           where cust.Practice.Any(p => p.locality.Contains(location) || 
                 cust.DoctorSpecialtys.Any(ds => ds.specialty.Contains(specialty))
           order by cust.Fee
           select cust;
```

As a word of advice, you should take care in naming your classes and properties. Classes shouldn't be pluralized and collection should. (Your classes name should be `Doctor`, `Practice` and `DoctorSpecialty` or even just `Specialty` and your collection on `Doctor` should be `Practices` and `Specialties`) Plus should keep a firm pattern for property capitalization. `location` and `clinicname` are all lower case and others are like `DoctorSpecialtys` are UpperCamel. Which naming convention you use isn't important lowerCamel, UpperCamel, alllower, but choose one and stick to it :D Your code will be a lot more readable.

And a personal favorite of mine a sort of personal war, as **Uncle Bob** said in **[Clean Code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship-ebook/dp/B001GSTOAM/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1388826773&sr=8-1&keywords=clean%20code)** *Use meaningful names*. The `info` part of the `DoctorsContext.doctorsinfo` doesn't say anything. **Every** property/field or every classes is a piece of information. So adding a trailing `info` is just noise. So why not remove it and just call the property `DoctorsContext.Doctors`.

Comment: Thank you for your good advise, I will take care of this now onwords

Answer (score 0):

```
DoctorsContext db = new DoctorsContext();
        var docs = from cust in db.doctorsinfo.Where(c => c.DoctorspecialityName.Contains(specialty) && c.DoctorLocation.Contains(location)).OrderBy(s=>s.Fee)
                   select cust;
```